# Is there any situation where a slot would not be initialized to its initform?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clos

I'm trying to learn about CLOS, and have written an example class.  It has 4 slots, named slot1-4.  slot2 has an initform, yet none the less I am getting this error: "The slot COMMON-LISP-USER::SLOT2 is unbound in the object".  I am failing to see how this is possible.  I am using SBCL and my code is as follows:

```
;;;; The following is meant to demonstrate some concepts of object initialisation
(defclass example ()
  ((slot1
    :initarg :slot1-arg
    :initform (error "must supply a slot1"))
   (slot2
    :initform "This is the initform"
    :reader slot2-reader
    :writer (setf slot2-writer))
   (slot3
    :accessor slot3-accessor
    :documentation "The third slot")
   (slot4)))

(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((instance example) &key)
  (setf (slot-value instance 'slot4)
        "this was set in INITIALIZE-INSTANCE"))

(let ((xampl (make-instance 'example
                            :slot1-arg "Must provide this or there will be an error")))
  (setf (slot3-accessor xampl)
        "it is necessary to initialize this slot, as there is not initform or initarg")
  (print (slot3-accessor xampl))
  (setf (slot-value xampl 'slot3) "this also works")
  (print (slot-value xampl 'slot3))
  (print (slot2-reader xampl)))
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your situation in `SBCL 1.4.5.debian` and `GNU CLISP 2.49.60+`. How are you running this?

Comment: I am using SLIME.  It seems that restarting my SBCL connection and re-evaluating the buffer solved my issue.